# How to get defaulValue of YouCanBookMe/react-datetime component?

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

I am using react-dateTime version"react-datetime": "^2.8.10",
I am using default Value. When i click on edit button i get the default value of react-dateTime. but when i update data and i am not changing the datetime.I want that that defaultValue.and when i update data with out changing date-time.i get current date-time.Then in that case how to get that defaultValue.
How to get defaultValue of react-DateTime?

```
renderForm:function(){
    var yesterday = Datetime.moment().subtract( 1, 'day' );
        var valid = function( current ){
        return current.isAfter( yesterday );
        };
        var dateTimeStart=moment(this.props.todo_start_at);
        var dateTimeEnd=moment(this.props.todo_end_at);
        console.log("dateTimeStart ",dateTimeStart)
        console.log("dateTimeEnd ",dateTimeEnd)
    return( 
        <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate}>
            <input type="text"ref={(value)=>{
                this.input=value
            }}defaultValue={this.props.todo_text}/>
            <div className="column medium-4">
                When To Start
                <Datetime input={ true } isValidDate={ valid } dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"  defaultValue= { dateTimeStart }onChange={ this.handleDateTimeStart } />
            </div>
            <div className="column medium-4">
                When To End
                <Datetime input={ true } isValidDate={ valid } dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" defaultValue= { dateTimeEnd }onChange={ this.handleDateTimeEnd }  />
            </div>
                <br/>
            <button type="button" className="button" onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update</button>
        </form>
        )
},
```

handleupdate

```
handleUpdate:function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //console.log(this.dateTimeStart.value);
        var startDate=this.state.dateTimeStart.value;
        console.log(startDate);
        var todoStartDate= moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
        var dueDate=this.state.dateTimeEnd.value;
        var todoEndDate=moment(dueDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
        console.log("handle update",todoEndDate)
        this.props.editTask(this.props.todo_id,this.input.value,todoStartDate,todoEndDate);
        this.toggleState();
    },
```

Comment: can you show `handleUpdate` method ?

Comment: yes..this ishandleUpdate.    handleUpdate:function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log(this.dateTimeStart.value);
  var startDate=this.state.dateTimeStart.value;
  console.log(startDate);
  var todoStartDate= moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  var dueDate=this.state.dateTimeEnd.value;
  var todoEndDate=moment(dueDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  console.log("handle update",todoEndDate)
this.props.editTask(this.props.todo_id,this.input.value,todoStartDate,todoEndDate);
  this.toggleState();},

Comment: what's the initial value of `this.state.dateTimeStart` and `this.state.dateTimeEnd` ?

Comment: initial value is dateTimeStart:'',
  dateTimeEnd:''

Comment: and you are updating these values only when user change these dates ?

Comment: and i am using this function for onchage datetimefor end date handleDateTimeEnd: function (newDateTime) {
    this.setState({ 
     dateTimeEnd: newDateTime
        });
  },

Comment: no..its not neccessary. user should update the date. if user does not update or change the dates then i want to get that default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you are initialising the `state` value by `""` (blank value), and updating that when user changes the date, otherwise not. So in that case when user is not updating the value `this.state.dateTimeStart.value` will be `undefined`, previous value (default value) will be present in `this.props.todo_start_at`.

You need to take that default value when user is not doing any change.

Use these line inside `handleUpdate` method:

```
var startDate = this.state.dateTimeStart.value || this.props.todo_start_at;
var dueDate = this.state.dateTimeEnd.value || this.props.todo_end_at;
```

Comment: thank you so much sir [@MayankShukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5185595/mayank-shukla). you solved my problem.